# Retrieval of all the invoices of particular contact id in xero

Tags: xero-api

In xero, if we create a contact. Using that contact we perform couple of sales invoice and purchase bills and few of them get paid. Now I want to obtain the list of the invoices `groupedBy` ContactID in ***php***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xero have recently released functionality that allows this in an easy way.

You can use the ContactIDs query parameter on the invoices endpoint like the following:

```
GET ../Invoices?ContactIDs=623e392d-7402-40e4-a54c-fdf29783e9a4
```

You can also do this for more than one ContactID by supplying a comma separated list of ContactIDs.

You can find more information about this in [this handy blog post](https://devblog.xero.com/new-filtering-on-the-accounting-api-b8acee14ec25)

Comment: thanks for your response,
I need bit different than this, I have list of contact and listing all the invoice ***grouped*** under the contact... not just viewing the invoices belonging to  certain contactID..

Thanks...

Comment: The similar endpoint for Contact IDs does not seem to work.  Have you tried that one?  I keep getting Not Found